# TurboYourPC_Setup.exe

Tags: malware

I think I already know the answer but I will ask anyway.  I clicked on something that downloaded this malware using my Opera browser - then clicked on the file from the browser (by accident I was intending to open the folder) and got a message along the lines "couldn't be unpacked."  I then opened the containing folder and deleted it.  All in Ubuntu 14.04 - I take it my system hasn't been compromised as 1. it's Windows Malware, 2. it didn't even unpack and 3. I never entered my my sudo password.  Apologies for my density on this but my nerves are frayed from 1001 other things today too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to give out breezy assurances about not worrying about malware. Malware is getting stealthier and nastier all the time. If so many big websites have been hacked, is there any reason to believe that an ordinary user can't get hacked too?

You shouldn't search for junk to download in Opera. If I were you I'd uninstall it. I don't think it's a good idea to look for junk to download in Firefox either. QupZilla from the Ubuntu Software Center is a better web browser for this purpose. QupZilla is fast, it can import bookmarks from Firefox, it has AdBlock installed by default, and it keeps the junk out of the way of your most frequently used web browser.

QupZilla has renamed itself as Falkon and be installed by the following command in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo snap install falkon
```

Comment: I didn't try and download anything, I clicked on an "about us" link that started a download.

Comment: That's a stealthy, nasty way to start an unwanted download.

Comment: Indeed it is.  I had only clicked on 1 or 2 links from a mainstream news media site as well to end up at the malware site.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. it's Windows Malware,
> 2. it didn't even unpack and
> 3. I never entered my my sudo password.

1. If you have Wine installed then your system has a layer of compatibility to Windows, that includes compatibility to malware of some degree. Having Mono installed can be a similar risk, as it can run (some) exe-files too.
2. Watch these messages closely: Who or which process or application gave that error message. Some strategies of malware authors include to give you such error messages leaving the impression that it failed while the malware installed and is running properly in the background.
3. Malware does not necessarily require administrative access. Currently popular patterns like encrypting your important files and asking for ransom is such an example.

Another questions is how did it even execute? Typical browsers prevent you from drive by downloads and instantly executing them. So who did ran this program? You? Rule of thumb: Never download, install or run something you weren't looking for.

Apparmor is a security solution built into Ubuntu that confines application access. It ships rules for Firefox but as far as I can remember it's focus is to protect the system (otherwise users would complain about being nagged). I don't know about if Opera integrates with Apparmor and how it protects you against drive by downloads, but if the download was executed then that's already one step too far and your criteria to judge are very unsafe. Being even more cautious also not desirable to backup your important data now, because you might contaminate your backups and fresh system installtions in the future.

If you haven't been consciously running data forensics software to monitor what exactly this application did then it's not safe to make any judgment. You should not use this system anymore and you should change your habits if somehow there is the possibility that you triggered the execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like wine is not installed. You tried to open `exe` by Archive Manager. So nothing bad has happened.

Just remove that file and forget.

Windows malware can't affect Linux directly.

Comment: Correct, "An error occurred while loading the archive."  I just un-deleted the file and clicked on it to clarify happened.  Either I had compromised my system or not, knowing either way all important.